# why the mayavi crushed when I use property ‘mask_points’ in function quiver3d?

Tags: python, mayavi

why the mayavi crushed when I use property ‘mask_points’ in function quiver3d()? Because the array data is too much, I want to use 'mask_points'...but if I add this property in function quiver3d(), then the mayavi crushed...

Comment: Can you provide a working minimal sample of code that reproduces your error?